# Error using GitHub actions with R markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, github-actions

I'm new to using GitHub actions, so please be gentle with me! I'm trying to automate a script that I'm currently running using Windows Task Scheduler. I've written the yml code below and its stored (privately) on GitHub at jeremy-horne/Client/.github/workflows/

The RMD code is 900 lines long and works when run in R studio. It is stored on GitHub at jeremy-horne/Client
`

```
name: my_project

on:
  schedule:
    - cron: "18 17 */1 * *" # Every day at 18:17 
    
jobs:
  render-rmarkdown:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    # optionally use a convenient Ubuntu LTS + DVC + CML image
    #container: docker://dvcorg/cml:latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
            
      - name: Setup R
        uses: r-lib/actions/setup-r@v2
        
      #- name: Setup Pandoc
      #  uses: r-lib/actions/setup-pandoc@v2
        
      - name: Setup dependencies
        run: |
          R -e 'install.packages("renv")' 
          R -e 'renv::restore()'
          
      - name: Identify and email articles
        #env: 
        #  repo_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }} 
        run: |
         Rscript -e 'rmarkdown::render(input = "My_Markdown_Code.Rmd")'
            if [[ "$(git status --porcelain)" != "" ]]; then
            git config --local user.name "$GITHUB_ACTOR"
            git config --local user.email "$GITHUB_ACTOR@users.noreply.github.com"
            git add *
            git commit -m "Auto update Report"
            git push origin
          fi
```

`

The error I get says "render-rmarkdown
there is no package called ‘rmarkdown’"

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Did you include `rmarkdown` in your `renv` setup? You need to make sure to install all the packages that are needed to run the code in the new environment. It may run locally if you have additional packages installed outside your `renv` environment. What's in your `renv.lock` file?

Comment: Thank you! Ok, this is where I am a real novice in this as I say! What is an renv.lock file? I suspect that's my problem - what should one contain and where do I store it?

Comment: Well the code you posted uses `install.packages("renv")` and `renv::restore()` so I was assuming you were already familiar with the `renv` package. If not, check out the documentation here: https://rstudio.github.io/renv/index.html. You can create a new lockfile with `renv::snapshot()`. Then you would want to save that to your repo so the workflow can find it and use it to load all the packages needed to run your Rscript command.

Comment: Ah, thank you! I've now learnt properly what lock files are and created one - all good there. However, I now seem to be getting an error that says render-rmarkdown
install of package 'curl' failed [error code 1] - have attempted to follow advice in the Rstudio post below, but to no avail, so if anyone has any suggestions, please let me know! 

https://community.rstudio.com/t/error-when-checking-r-package-on-ubuntu-with-github-actions-but-not-with-rhub/108899/3